# splitting string in c++, with no clear sign?

Tags: c++, string

Given the following input: `test="<a,b>,<cdf,d>,<e,ff>..."` how can I split it into pieces such that I will get:

```
<a,b>
<cdf,d>
<e,ff>
```

Comment: Are your substrings always of the same format? i.e. single characters inside `<>` separated by a `,`?

Comment: there are tons of `explode / split` string functions here on StackOverflow for C++

Comment: @Berto99 didn't find one to match my ase

Comment: @cigien yes they are

Comment: It looks like you can use `">,"` as clear separator.

Comment: @eerorika what about the last one, plus there is no code to separate using char for c++

Comment: @daniel `what about the last one` According to the pattern, the last token would be preceded by `">,"` just like the other ones. You can use the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to match the individual pieces, like this:

```
std::regex re{R"(<\w+,\w+>)"};
```

and then easily construct the `vector<string>` of results like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> pieces;

std::sregex_token_iterator begin(str.begin(), str.end(), re), end;

std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(pieces));
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TEoKG7).